# Function-like classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to do `new new A` in JS with `A !== Function`? What's the desired structure of A then?

Comment: Did you mean `new A` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm aware what the `new` keyword is. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in theory.

```
function A() { 
  return function B() {
  } 
}
> new new A
  B {}
```

or

```
> new new A()
> new new A() ()
```

since the parentheses are optional with the `new` operator.

This takes advantage of the fact that a constructor may return something other than the constructed object. It is extremely unclear why anyone would ever want to do this. Also, this does not change the fact that `new` can only be invoked on a function.

#### Dept. of Curiosities

This

```
function A() { return A; }
```

allows you to do this

```
new new new new new new new new new new new new A
```

which there is no point whatsoever in doing.

#### Prototype Chains

You know that calling `new` on a constructor constructs an object with the prototype for that constructor. However, if you return any object other than `this` from a constructor, `this`, along with its associated prototype, is forever lost to the world. Whatever object you return has its own prototype, coming from wherever--not that of A. This applies equally to the case here where the constructor returns a function, in which case the relevant prototype is `Function.prototype`. Is there any way to arrange it, in the unlikely event that we cared, so that `new A` continues to return a functioning function, which we can do a `new` on, while also having access to `A.prototype`?

Not easily. If you want additional properties on the `function B` returned from `new A`, then you can just add those properties before returning `function B`.

Comment: Excellent! That's the answer I've been expecting. Is it a standard-compliant behaviour?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Yes, this is perfectly valid ECMAScript behavior per the [`[[Construct]]` specifiction](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2): `Let result be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property... If Type(result) is Object then return result.` (i.e., if the function's behavior when called returns an object, use that object as the return value of the constructing `new` call). Functions are objects, so it's a valid return value for a constructor.

Comment: @torazaburo Don't you have an idea on how to restore a prototype chain there?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph `A` is a function that constructs a constructor (we'll call this constructed constructor `B`). When you construct an instance of `B`, the instance uses `B`'s prototype chain. Simply build your prototype chain around `B` in instead of `A` -- `A` is a constructor that makes constructors, not proper objects. If using `B.prototype` is not practical for some reason (you haven't said *why* on earth you need to support `new new A`), you can also have `B` return an object created with `Object.create(A.prototype)`.

Comment: @apsillers I forgot why on earth did I need it myself, but then remembered that I'd like to `var User = new Model(...), user = new User(...);`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. `A` must be a function, regardless of its return value.

Source: [ECMAScript 5 spec for the `new` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2):

> If constructor does not implement the [[Construct]] internal method,
>   throw a TypeError exception.

From the [Function specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2), we can see that `[[Construct]]` is a special internal (inaccessible) property of Function objects.

Comment: This is little more than a curiosity, but: the spec does not disallow non-function *host objects* from implementing an internal `[[Construct]]` property, though I don't know of any actual host environment that supplies non-function constructors.

Comment: Should `A` be a function or `new A` be a function? Why is it impossible to tweak a constructor of a type so that constructed objects would have an internal `[[Construct]]`?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph It is not possible to directly alter an object's internal properties from JS code, which is part of the reason why they're called "internal". To answer your first question: `A` must be a function and the result of `new A` must also be a function.

Comment: Both `A` and `(new A)` must be functions or, as apsillers points out, special (probably non-existent) objects that the runtime endows with a `[[Construct]]` property. `[[Construct]]` is purely in the realm of the host runtime; the executed JavaScript code cannot touch it.

Comment: @joews Note that question specifies `A !== Function` not `typeof A != "function"` (that is, `A` could be a function, just not the particular `Function` constructor function), so it *is* technically possible, per torazaburo's answer.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.